# Can you receive cards you do not own from a card request?

Tags: clash-royale

I have terrible luck in getting cards. I am basically still using starter cards but have made it to arena 3, and now find they are inadequate to handle some of the cards my opponents use. If I were to join a clan, would I be able to request a card that I do not have, as long as it is unlock-able within my arena bracket, and then have one in my collection?

Comment: You can only request cards you have unlocked previously. Sorry but you are going to have to get lucky and win a first copy from a chest or purchase from the daily store. Not making this an answer as I don't have any evidence to hand, just my own experience

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being part of a clan will allow you to request either 10 common cards or 1 rare card several times a day.
However, you can only make a request for cards currently in your collection.

You cannot request epic or legendary cards, nor can you request a card you do not already own unfortunately.

You will have to wait until you are lucky enough to:

1. Win one copy from a chest
2. Purchase one copy from the daily store

Comment: If you unlock a rare by getting one card, then donate that card, you can request when you technically dont have that card :)

Comment: you have had a copy, therefore unlocking the card permanently. But yes, the same as if you use all copies you have to upgrade, you can still use it. You can only request troops that you can use in battle

Answer (score 1):

With new trade tokens, you can now get cards you have not unlocked through a trade, as long as your clan mate initiates the trade with a trade token